# Why can't FindAncestor find root UserControl when called inside {Binding} element in a DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf

First, sorry about the title. Happy to change it to something better if you have suggestions.

I'm new to wpf and can't wrap my head around this problem. I have a property List<> Serieslist in my UserControl datacontext. Item's in this list are [livecharts](https://lvcharts.net/) SeriesCollection charts (I think this problem is related to my incompetence with wpf and not to livecharts). I can find the UserControl ancestor from StackPanel, but when inside lvc:CartesianChart with Series="{Binding}" I can't.

My XAML:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <StackPanel >
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Serieslist}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>

                                <!--These Bindings work as intended-->
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.From, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.To, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>


                                <lvc:CartesianChart Height="100" Series="{Binding}" Zoom="X" Grid.Column="0" DisableAnimations="True" DataTooltip="{x:Null}">
                                    <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>

                                        <!--These Bindings don't-->
                                        <lvc:Axis LabelFormatter="{Binding Path=DataContext.Formatter, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" 
                                                  MinValue = "{Binding Path=DataContext.From, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" 
                                                  MaxValue = "{Binding Path=DataContext.To, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                                  RangeChangedCommand="{Binding Path=DataContext.Axis_OnRangeChangedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
                                    </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                                    <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                                        <lvc:Axis Foreground="DodgerBlue" MinValue="0"/>
                                        <lvc:Axis Foreground="IndianRed" Position="RightTop" MinValue="0" MaxValue="10"/>
                                    </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                                </lvc:CartesianChart>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
```

I understand the {Binding } scope changes when entering the CartesianChart, but still why Isn't this way of using RelativeSource finding the right source for binding?

Also these livecharts axis elements are found inside my live visual tree. [Bars] is the UserControl and no other UserControls are present[image: visual tree]

Naming the ancestor element and finding the datacontext with the name seems hacky for such simple(?) problem. Also I might need to reuse these usercontrols and I'd like to avoid the name=usercontrol1 name=usercontrol2 name=usercontrol3 etc way of accessing parent control.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you see any BindingErrors logged in the Output Window of VisualStudio?

Comment: Yes. Here's one:

System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.UserControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.From; DataItem=null; target element is 'Axis' (Name=''); target property is 'MinValue' (type 'Double')

Comment: I don't know this control but maybe the problem is the same as with DataGrid, where the Columns are not part of the Visual Tree and there you cannot find an Ancestor like this. 
Maybe this helps a bit: https://thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/

Comment: @kahko: There seems to be no `UserControl` in your visual tree. Try to change the `AncestorType` to `Window`.

Comment: @FlatEric That solution works and even with two-way binding and functions. Thank you. Still feels like there should be simpler way of doing this.